# 1997 toyota camry V6 3.0L fuse box wiring

Tags: electrical, troubleshooting

how to wire the wires under the dashboard that hook to the fuse box because there has been several that have been untwisted because of the fact that I had a guy come and hook a system up for me and for some reason he messed with the wiring that runs from the fuse box.

Comment: I feel your pain.  Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair...

Comment: Can you provide pictures of the wires in question?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a frustrating issue.  It sounds like the person who did some work for you did a poor job.  That happens.  It happens more often by those who don't guarantee their work.

In life when you want to solve a problem you get to use three resources 1) Money  2) Energy and 3) Time.   This issue is one of those.

You could go to a legitimate automotive repair facility and hire a mechanic to fix the issue.  It could be a ten minute repair, or a four hour repair.  And any mechanic you go to will want to bill by the hour.  No surprise.  Just send money. Lots of money.

An other way is to find a friend who works on cars or electrical systems as a hobby and get them to help you troubleshoot and repair the issue.  I have a few friends like that.  You could be creative...  Any trade schools teach automotive mechanics in your area?  Contact them, offer a $$ reward for successful repair.  Who knows, perhaps the teacher is looking for real world repairs and may fix yours for free.  Cheaper then paying for an official repair.

Third choice is to fix this yourself.  You'd have to invest sometime and energy.  But, you will gain the satisfaction of fixing something yourself, something others on this site have discovered.  Required skills:

- Basic Electricity -- I'd recommend [the basic electricity Kahn Academy online course](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/electrical-engineering/introduction-to-ee) . You want to learn about current, voltage and safety practices.  Learn how to use a volt-ohm-meter.
- Read up on good practices for automotive style wiring.  Some helpful sites include [Ron Francis Tips](http://www.offroadxtreme.com/engine-tech/ignition-electronics-efi/top-ten-wiring-tips-with-ron-francis-wiring/), [FourWheeler Tips](http://www.fourwheeler.com/how-to/electrical/1603-tips-to-rewire-your-vehicle-like-a-professional/), and [automotive wiring videos](https://www.google.com/search?bih=930&tbm=vid&q=how%20to%20wire%20a%20ca)
- You will want a wiring diagram for your car.  I'd start at either Haynes or Chilton repair manual for your car.  The cost for a new paper manual is around $30 at your local auto parts store.  Money well spent, for all future repairs on your car.  You may not choose to make repairs yourself, but a close read of a manual will tell you what's involved.  In many cases you will be able to find a wiring diagram via online search.  There are many online hobbyist forum discussion sites, often those that specialize in one make / model of vehicle.
- You don't really need to make a lot of tool purchases.  One thing you will need is a volt-ohm-meter. These are great tools to have. You can find a decent meter in the range of $15 to $50.  Most meters in this price range will have the tools you need.  The majority of your work will be reading voltage (0 to 14 volts DC ).
- You may also share your location.  If you lived in my area, I'd be glad to help you / teach you on this stuff.
- At this point you are probably ready to start the troubleshooting process.  You will be using the volt ohm meter to read voltages.  Do you see 0 volts on all wires that go to ground?  Do you see 14 volts on powered wires?

[image: voltmeter on battery]

From what you've described, this is not a particularly difficult repair.  It just takes time and patience.  You can't be in a rush. In fact, my guess is once you open stuff up and closely inspect the work done by the person who added your "system" you will immediately see something that just doesn't look right to you.

One rule for working on cars when you are starting out learning this stuff.  And its a pretty big rule.

> NEVER WORK ON A CAR THAT YOU NEED TO DRIVE TO WORK TOMORROW.

Good luck with this stuff.